# Find Hidden Tweet Location

Tags: api, twitter

There is a public tweet and the location of this tweet is private. Can I find where the tweet was thrown in any way? It is enough to be known as a city, not a net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way for a Tweet to have both public and private data associated with it. If the location value is not set in the Tweet object, then the user chose not to associate location information at the time of posting. Therefore, it is not possible to retrieve the location in these cases, since it was never set and stored.